# Android: Интернет-запрос в Java

Tags: android, html, java

Нужно отправить на сайт запрос: авторизоваться на нём,а потом взаимодействовать со страницами его.

Не знаю как это реализовать в Java, вроде через POST, но не знаю всех подводных камней,а можно ли это сделать через библиотеку Jsoup? 
Хотелось бы видеть пример. Спасибо)

Вот часть кода авторизации на сайте:

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2>
      <tr>
        <td>Ваше Имя:</td>
        <td colspan=2><input type=text name=login value='' maxlength=20 style='width:155;'></td>
     </tr><tr>
        <td>Пароль:</td>
        <td><input type=password name=pass value='' maxlength=20 style='width:120;'></td>
        <td><img border=0 src="i/keyboard2.gif" style='cursor: hand' onClick="KeypadShow();"></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=3 align=center><input type=submit value='Войти' class="wbtn" style="width:80;"></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=3 align=center><input type=button class='wbtn' value='Регистрация' onclick='window.location="reg.php"'></td>
    </tr></table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Где начальный тег form? Там точно должно быть указано в аттрибуте method.

[Пример POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376326/jsoup-form-posting)
, там ещё в ответах пару ссылок на парсинг куков.

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно же и без магии Jsoup.....

Как я понимаю эту библиотеку Вы собираетесь использовать в Андроид приложении??
Если да, то лучше заюзать HttpClient  который уже встроен во все вресии ведроида. И умеет отправлять POST запрос. И работать с хедерами в которых в каждом запросе указываеться некий признак по которому, можно определить что то т или иной пользователь зарегистрированы, что важно для авторизации.

Не стоит добавлять лишние библиотеки в Андроид приложение, не нужны они там)

Дополнительная информация об HttpClient -[тут](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)